# mitmproxy change server host by path

Tags: mitmproxy

I trying to change connection host depending on path, the problem in `context`, I though it is created when flow created, but it shared  between requests. So i lost here, this is what i tried

```
import re
import os
os.environ['PAGER'] = 'cat'
from libmproxy.models import HTTPResponse
from netlib.http import Headers
from netlib.tcp import Address
def request(context, flow):
# flow.request.path
        context.log("server %s " % repr(flow.server_conn) ,"info");
        if flow.request.host.endswith("google.com"):
                if re.match(flow.request.path, "/"):
                        context.address = "10.0.0.15";
                else:
                        context.address = "google.com"

def serverconnect(context, server_conn):
        if hasattr(context, 'address'):
                context.log("server changed from %s" % (repr(server_conn)) ,"info");
                server_conn.address = Address(address=(context.address, server_conn.address.port))
                context.log("server changed to %s" % (repr(server_conn)) ,"info");
        else:
                context.log("server NOT changed %s" % repr(server_conn),"info");
```

Important note:

I need to not change `HOST:` in http request headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found reason and solution myself,

reason is keepalive, you need to close connections when you switch hosts, because otherwise you will not be go to `serverconnect` routine and use last connected host:

```
import re
import os
os.environ['PAGER'] = 'cat'
from libmproxy.models import HTTPResponse
from netlib.http import Headers
from netlib.tcp import Address
def request(context, flow):
# flow.request.path
        context.log("server %s " % repr(flow.server_conn) ,"info");
        if flow.request.host.endswith("google.com"):
                if re.match(flow.request.path, "/"):
                        context.address = "10.0.0.15";
                else:
                        context.address = "google.com"
#here is solution
                if repr(server_conn.get_state().get('timestamp_start')) != 'None':
                        print(server_conn.get_state().get('timestamp_start'))
                        server_conn.close()


def serverconnect(context, server_conn):
        if hasattr(context, 'address'):
                context.log("server changed from %s" % (repr(server_conn)) ,"info");
                server_conn.address = Address(address=(context.address, server_conn.address.port))
                context.log("server changed to %s" % (repr(server_conn)) ,"info");
        else:
                context.log("server NOT changed %s" % repr(server_conn),"info");
```